# fetching the JSON object numbers which fetch a particular value

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I have a JSON data from which I need to parse a path and get a value from that JSON data.
My JSON data format is like:

```
"PAYLOAD": [
        {
            "ModuleID": "40",
            "ModuleName": "Job Posting"

        },
        {
            "ModuleID": "40",
            "ModuleName": "Job Posting"

        },
        {
            "ModuleID": "180",
            "ModuleName": "Invoice"
        },.................
```

Now I am checking the key-values like :

```
boolean hello=jp.getString("PAYLOAD.ModuleName").contains("Job Posting");
```

It is fetching me that whether the value "Job Posting" exists in the JSON data or not , but not the JSON object numbers which have this value.
I don't want to use for-loops to fetch the object numbers.
Is there any short way of getting the object numbers which have a particular value corresponding to a particular path?

Answer (score 0):

The following expression

```
PAYLOAD[?(@.ModuleName='Job Posting')].ModuleID
```

returning

```
["40","40"]
```

You can give a try.

Comment: But this expression doesn't gives me the object numbers of the Payload object which contains (ModuleName as "Job Posting")

Comment: My bad. It should be `PAYLOAD[?(@.ModuleName=='Job Posting')].ModuleID`

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting my code snippet here. Make sure that you have [JSONPath](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/json-path-2.2.0.jar) jar file in your path. This is printing the desired output `["40","40"]`

```
String JSONString = "{\"PAYLOAD\": [{\"ModuleID\": \"40\",\"ModuleName\": \"Job Posting\"}, {\"ModuleID\": \"40\",\"ModuleName\": \"Job Posting\"}, {\"ModuleID\": \"180\",\"ModuleName\": \"Invoice\"}]}";
    net.minidev.json.JSONArray jsonArray = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
            .parse(JSONString).read(
                    "PAYLOAD[?(@.ModuleName=='Job Posting')].ModuleID");
    System.out.println("Result: " + jsonArray.toString());
```